# IntelliJ will not reload class definition after change of Groovy class

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

I have a Groovy class (class A) that originally had a constructor signature:

```
Profiler(String name, String method, boolean isLeader)
```

I added the class to another groovy class (class B). I changed the constructor signature to:

```
Profiler(String name, String method)
```

However, class B is still using the original class. I've tried rebuilding, removing the target with groovy stubs, removing the class files, doing a maven clean install, but it still holds on to the old version of class A.

I'm using IntelliJ. It's probably a hopeless cause since there are too many unknown variables. Has anyone else seen something like this and was able to solve it?

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  You can't have a constructor like `Profiler(String name, String method, boolean isLeader)` in a class named `A` and you can't have a constructor like `Profiler(String name, String method)` in a class named `B`.  It isn't possible.  The language doesn't allow it.

Comment: class A and class B are not the class names.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't experience that but you can try find out the reason for that by doing the following:

1. Put a breakpoint into the target place (class B, before the *Profiler* class instantiation)
2. Start debug session
3. Wait until the breakpoint is hit
4. Evaluate *Profiler.class.protectionDomain.codeSource.location* - it will show use compiled bytecode (*.class) location in the local file system and you can physically remove it

Comment: When I evaluate Profiler.class.protectionDomain.codeSource.location, it throws a MissingPropertyException.

Comment: Never mind. I have to fully qualify the name of the class (I'm not doing an import). It is pointing to a jar file. Thanks!